# How can I monitor the currently open connections of an Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am debugging a problem with an Azure Cosmos DB and would like to see the currently open connections to the DB. Is there a metric for this that I could search for in the Azure Monitor or where and how can I find this status information?

Comment: The monitoring would be on the service where your application is hosted. For example, if you are running in an Azure VM, it would be on the VM's connections metrics. Where/which service are you hosting the app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is actually how to monitor the metrics of the Cosmos DB independently from any consumer. So e.g. how many connections are currently open on the DB side. At the consumer side I have an Azure App Service running a containerized Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you are using Azure App Service. Azure App Service has a way to monitor established connections (and even those in TIME_WAIT).

Azure Monitor has the `Connections` metrics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/web-sites-monitor#understand-metrics

Also, App Service has the Diagnostics Tool that includes Connections: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html

Your application runs in an App Service which is actually in an [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans), that's the machine that is maintaining the connections. If you have many applications sharing the same App Service Plan, you'd see the connection information from all.

Comment: Thank you for the hint regarding app service monitoring. That let's me analyze the open TCP connections of the app service. However, I would still like to see number of open connections and other metrics of the CosmosDB directly.

Comment: You cannot see the open connections on the Cosmos DB side. What "other metrics" are you needing?